# Regex to find missing space after html tags

Tags: c#, javascript, regex

From the set more then 10000 rows of text, I need to find all instances of string where space after a set of html tags are missing.
Set of HTML tags are limited they are as follow.

`<b> </b>, <em> </em>, <span style="text-decoration: underline;" data-mce-style="text-decoration: underline;"> </span>
<sub> </sub>, <sup> </sup>, <ul> </ul>, <li> </li>, <ol> </ol>`

After running Regx following string should come in result.

`Hi <b>all</b>good morning.`

As in this case we have missed sapce after bold tag.

Comment: I don't see how you could possibly expect that output from that input, unless you hard-code the output.  And -1 for trying to use regex for what is well known to require a stack.

Comment: You've tagged this both C# and JavaScript - which language *are* you using?

Comment: @bdares: This is a perfect fit for a regex. At least if I understood the question correctly.

Comment: @bdares output is not needed I, just need to find all instances where such strings are present.

Comment: its a good question just badly worded so people are misinterpreting what is being asked. hes saying for only the above set of tags he needs regex to make sure that there is spaced inbetween them so he doesnt end up with something like the Hi <b>all</> but instead gets Hi <b> all </b>, as this is using html im guessing this is a web application, hence the use of both c# the language he is using and javascript, as he would be happy with a javascript script to implement to do this.

Comment: Thanks @RhysW, following cases alright

Comment: Thanks @RhysW, Just one thing space withing the tag or after the tag is alright e.g `<b>all</> good morning` and `<b>all </>good morning` both are fine.

Comment: @djay: How is the second case alright? There's a space missing after the closing tag (assuming you meant `</b>`, not `</>`).

Comment: @TimPietzcker it is ook because there is a space BEFORE the closing tag, hes trying to get rid of any places where words arent given a space between them because of the html tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming C#:

```
StringCollection resultList = new StringCollection();
Regex regexObj = new Regex("^.*<(?:/?b|/?em|/?su[pb]|/?[ou]l|/?li|span style=\"text-decoration: underline;\" data-mce-style=\"text-decoration: underline;\"|/span)>(?! ).*$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResult.Success) {
    resultList.Add(matchResult.Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```

will return all lines in your file where there's at least one space after one of the tags in your list.

Input:

```
This </b> is <b> OK
This <b> is </b>not OK
Neither <b>is </b> this.
```

Output:

```
This <b> is </b>not OK
Neither <b>is </b> this.
```

**Explanation:**

```
^      # Start of line
.*     # Match any number of characters except newlines
<      # Match a <
(?:    # Either match a...
 /?b   #  b or /b
|      # or 
 /?em  #  em or /em
|...   # etc. etc.
)      # End of alternation
>      # Match a >
(?! )  # Assert that no space follows
.*     # Match any number of characters until...
$      # End of line
```

Comment: +1 for awesome description too, used regex before but this explanation takes the cake!